# htaccess HTTP 200 message body

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http

How can i add a message body to my HTTP 200 response from .htaccess ?
like Hello world! :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 10 Oct 2010 23:26:07 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) mod_ssl/2.2.8 OpenSSL/0.9.8g
Last-Modified: Sun, 26 Sep 2010 22:04:35 GMT
ETag: "45b6-834-49130cc1182c0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 13
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

Hello world!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't something you do in `.htaccess` alone. Short of directly requesting a file that returns the "Hello World!" response, what you can do in `.htaccess` is *rewrite the requested URL* to a file that returns the "Hello World!" response.

For example, given a request for `http://example.com/foo` then you could rewrite this request using mod_rewrite in `.htaccess` to a plain text file that outputs the response. For example:

In `/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^foo$ hello-world.txt [L]
```

In `/hello-world.txt`:

```
Hello World!
```

Of course, you could simply request `http://example.com/hello-world.txt` directly (unless you add additional directives to *redirect* such direct requests).